# OWL-API : Identify owl format based on its string contents

Tags: java, owl, ontology, protege, owl-api

I have owl files with different formats (RDF/XML , Turtle, Manchester OWL Syntax). I want to identify the format based on its contents as different format has its own style.

E.g

**RDF/XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >]>
<rdf:RDF
xmlns="namespace#"
xml:base="namespace"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="namespace"/>
<!-- namespace#my1 -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="namespace#my1"/>
<!-- namespace#my2 -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="namespace#my2"/>
<!-- namespace#prop1 -->
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="namespace#prop1"/>
<!-- namespace#prop2 -->
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="namespace#prop2"/>
<!-- namespace#A -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="namespace#A"/>
<!-- namespace#B -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="namespace#B"/>
<!-- namespace#C -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="namespace#C"/>
<!-- namespace#P -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="namespace#P"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**Manchester OWL Syntax :**

```
Prefix: : <namespace#>
Prefix: owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
Prefix: rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
Prefix: xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
Prefix: xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
Prefix: rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
Ontology: <namespace>
ObjectProperty: my2
ObjectProperty: my1
DataProperty: prop2
DataProperty: prop1
Class: B
Class: A
Class: P 
Class: C
```

So even though I have two files having same name `myOntology.owl` I can identify its format based of above contents (by just opening in editor). How to do this using OWL-API in JAVA ? Also how load methods from `OWLOntologyManager` differentiates them ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think that one approach used by some tools (e.g., Protege) is to just try loading it as each of the different supported formats (RDF/XML, OWL/XML, TTL, Manchester, etc.), until one of them works or they all fail.  If one succeeds, then that was probably the correct format.  It's very unlikely that more that a file would be correct in more than one format (aside from some trivial cases where the file is empty, just whitespace, etc.).

Comment: How `loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument` method from `OWLOntologyManager` works then ? As it accepts file in form of stream right. So I tried to create `StreamDocumentSource` and look for it's _format_. But  `isFormatKnown()` method gives FALSE. And how can I do the loading in different formats ?

Comment: The approach I mentioned is *one* possible approach that can be used when the format *isn't* known.  If you *do* know the format in advance, then of course you can select an appropriate parser in advance.

Comment: little bit in doubt (I don't know the format of document), is it possible to load ontology in different formats (I guess load method handles it all). I mean are there any methods which accept the document format too, so I can try out the approach of trial and error for loading it.

Comment: Joshua is right, the approach in owl api is to try the parsers in sequence. The formats are mutually exclusive, except for OBO, which admits a Manchester syntax header.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the OWL serializations do not have explicit markers like other formats do.

OWL API just tries all formats it knows about until one passes; this is not always efficient but there is no other way of doing this.

On the other hand, the vast majority of parsers will detect errors within a few lines of the start. So failure is fairly fast.

For ontologies loading successfully, you can access the actual format with getFormat().

Comment: Is it possible to check the file format using parsers before loading it ? Like is there any method which accepts file OR string and returns the format of it ?

Comment: Computationally, testing the file format and loading it are the same thing for the parser

Comment: So I have to load ontology, before that I cant check its format.